# KVM installation & Prerequisite

Tags: command-line, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, cpuinfo

Before Installation of `KVM` we have to check our processor support visualization or not and we run a command i.e:

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Which gives output 0/1/2/3/4 depends on processor

if 0 then not support visualization else it support.

Anyone please explain the command i.e. what `egrep -c (vmx|svm)` stands for  ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

This searches if one of those two flags exist in the /proc/cpuinfo file.

SVM is flag related to the [AMD virtualization (AMD-V)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization). The CPU flag for AMD-V is "svm".

VMX is falg related to the [Intel virtualization (VT-x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization). The CPU flag for VT-x capability is "vmx";

`man egrep`

```
NAME
       grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep - print lines matching a pattern


DESCRIPTION
       grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
       named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines
       containing  a  match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the
       matching lines.

       In  addition,  three  variant  programs  egrep,  fgrep  and  rgrep  are
       available.   egrep  is  the  same  as  grep -E.
```

then egrep is same as gerp -E which means also from `man grep`

```
 -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  an extended regular expression
```

So in conclusion this will search the file /proc/cpuinfo for those cpu flags and then count the occurrence instead of printing the matching it counts matching number.

```
  -c, --count
              Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
              for  each  input  file.
```